# XeLaTex and Noto fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, xecjk

I get an error -

> xdvipdfmx:fatal: sfnt: Freetype failure...

- when trying to use Google Noto fonts.
How should I proceed?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK JP}

\begin{document}

すもももももももものうち。

\end{document}
```

Comment: Imho this patch http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2014-July/025387.html addresses this issue. But I don't know if and when it will find its way in the official xdvipdfmx (or if is is already there but this solve the issue). You could ask on the xetex list or on the texlive list.

Comment: @Pierre: Ulrike is right. I have confirmed that the xdvipdfmx based
on the current sources in the TeX Live repository works fine for
your example.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto I understand that the development version of `xdvipdfmx` has been updated with the patch. what is the simplest method to try it out? I'm using TeXLive 2014 on a Mac. thanx.

Comment: @Pierre: If you cannot make or obtain a binary, please wait
for the TeX Live 2015.